# How to prove/disprove $\prod_{k=1}^{n}{cos(\frac{k\pi}{n})}=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{2^{n-1}}$ for odd n?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I was attempting a question and this came up as a result I needed to prove. I couldn't figure out a method, but I was thinking that it would be possible by considering the roots of $z^n=1$ or more specifically $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{z^k}=0$, but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(z) = \prod_{k=1}^n (z-e^{2 i k \pi/ n}) = z^n-1$$ $$\prod_{k=1}^n  \cos(k\pi /n)= 2^{-n}\prod_{k=1}^n (e^{i k \pi/ n}+e^{-i k \pi/ n})=2^{-n}\prod_{k=1}^n (1+e^{2 i k \pi/ n}) = 2^{-n} (-1)^n P(-1)$$